# Applying logic from a function to newly created HTML that was not originally in the HTML script

Tags: javascript, html, cloning

I have written some code for a small app that tracks daily tasks.  I am cloning the node with `id = 'active'` which has a button to transfer it into another column. The logic that is being used to do this will not work with the new cloned node created from the `createNewButton1`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Project Board</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app.css" />
    <script src="assets/scripts/app.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <header id="main-header">
      <h1>Project Planner</h1>
    </header>

  <div>
    <section id="active">
      <header>
        <h2>Days</h2>
      </header>
      <ul>
        <li
          id="p4"
          data-extra-info="Super important conference! Fictional but still!"
          class="card"
        >
          <h2>Monday</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </section>
```

```
Class ProjectItem {
  constructor(id, updateProjectListsFunction, type) {
    this.id = id;
    this.updateProjectListsHandler = updateProjectListsFunction;
    this.connectMoreInfoButton();
    this.connectSwitchButton(type);
    this.createNewButton1();
  }

  createNew () {
    const newItem = document.getElementById('active').querySelector('li');
    const cln = newItem.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('active').appendChild(cln);
  }


createNewButton1 () {

  const addNewButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
    addNewButton.addEventListener( 'click', this.createNew);
}
```

The button that causes a switch to another column uses an event listener and this will not apply to the new cloned node.

```
connectSwitchButton(type) {
    const projectItemElement = document.getElementById(this.id);
    let switchBtn = projectItemElement.querySelector('button:last-of-type');
    switchBtn = DOMHelper.clearEventListeners(switchBtn);
   
    switchBtn.textContent = type === 'active' ? 'Finish' : 'Activate';
    switchBtn.addEventListener(
      'click', 
      this.updateProjectListsHandler.bind(null, this.id)
    );
  }
```

Comment: It might help you get an answer if you cut your code down to a basic example showcasing the issue you are facing

Comment: 255 lines of code is not a [MCVE]

Comment: ok @CertainPerformance im new give me a break please

Comment: Don't take it personally - *everyone* who posts a question is expected to provide a [MCVE], not just newbies

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: @LajosArpad sure thing! https://jsfiddle.net/jxo9uzce/#&togetherjs=n04yHP3Afz

Comment: @LajosArpad after clicking create new there is a new task in the middle column...clicking on the "finish" button does not move it to the next column as it does the other two tasks that are already there

Comment: The asker obviously put in effort into solving this. He is a beginner, we shouldn't be so elitists as to make people less enthusiastic about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `click` event handler which will call `moveElement`. You also need to watch out for the id to avoid duplicating:

```
  createNew () {
    const newItem = document.getElementById('active').querySelector('li');
    const cln = newItem.cloneNode(true);
    cln.id = "p" + (document.querySelectorAll("#active > li").length + 1);
    document.getElementById('active').appendChild(cln);
    cln.addEventListener("click", function() {DOMHelper.moveElement(cln.id, "#finished-projects ul")});
  }
```

Test here: https://jsfiddle.net/gcL6e3kz/

Observation: This is unrelated to the problem you were asking about, but if I click on finish on all cards and then click on add new, then it will fail, because there is nothing to clone. It would be a good idea to create some templates via template literals for this purpose and then you could use them without having to assume that there is at least a card. Happy coding!

Comment: Ok thank you for the great advice ! I will give it a try I appreciate it I was trying everything I can think of which is why so many different lines may be commented out..I feel like it was on the tip of my tongue!

Comment: @MattLaszcz you are welcome. There are many opportunities to go wrong and you have probably had the right ideas, but you did not see them being right after testing them, because of other problems interfering with the results of the test. As you accumulate experience, you will get better and better in resolving these issues. And the current problem was great for you to gather experience. So no worries, you were already doing pretty well and the next time you will be doing even better.